# String.replace and same method call mutliple times

Tags: java, string, csv, security, optimization

I and my friend has written below code to prevent code injection in injection in CSV files. (written in java)

For big CSV files (say 400 columns, 10000 rows), the code is taking ~15 seconds in the worst case (all columns and rows are bad). Can anybody help me optimize it.

```java
public static String sanitizeInputForCSV(final String inputCSVRow) {
    String outputCSVRow = inputCSVRow;
    outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(outputCSVRow, "=");
    outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(outputCSVRow, "-");
    outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(outputCSVRow, "+");
    outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(outputCSVRow, "@");

    return outputCSVRow;
}

public static String escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(String inputString, String characterToEscape) {

    String outputString = inputString;

    // To replace the first ocurrance
    if (outputString.startsWith("\"" + characterToEscape)) {
        outputString = "\"" + " " + outputString.substring(1, outputString.length());
    } else if (outputString.startsWith(characterToEscape)) {
        outputString = " " + outputString.substring(0, outputString.length());
    }

    // To replace subsequent ocurrance
    outputString = outputString.replace(",\"" + characterToEscape, ",\"" + " " + characterToEscape);
    outputString = outputString.replace("," + characterToEscape, "," + " " + characterToEscape);

    return outputString;

}
```

### Update

Final optimized code that runs 4 times faster than above.

```
private static String sanitizeInputForCSVOpti1b(final String inputCSVRow) {
        StringBuilder outputCSVRow = new StringBuilder(inputCSVRow);
        outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSVOpti1b(outputCSVRow, '=');
        outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSVOpti1b(outputCSVRow, '-');
        outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSVOpti1b(outputCSVRow, '+');
        outputCSVRow = escapeMacroTriggersFromCSVOpti1b(outputCSVRow, '@');
        return outputCSVRow.toString();
    }

private static StringBuilder escapeMacroTriggersFromCSVOpti1b(StringBuilder inputRow, char characterToEscape) {
    StringBuilder outputRow;

    if (inputRow.length() == 0 || (inputRow.length() == 1 && inputRow.charAt(0) != characterToEscape)) {
        outputRow = inputRow;
    } else if (inputRow.length() == 1 && inputRow.charAt(0) == characterToEscape) {
        outputRow = new StringBuilder().append(' ').append(inputRow);
    } else {
        outputRow = new StringBuilder();

        // To replace the first ocurrance
        final char firstCharacter = inputRow.charAt(0);
        final char secondCharacter = inputRow.charAt(1);
        if (firstCharacter == '\"' && secondCharacter == characterToEscape) {
            outputRow.append(firstCharacter).append(' ').append(secondCharacter);
        } else if (firstCharacter == characterToEscape) {
            outputRow.append(' ').append(firstCharacter).append(secondCharacter);
        } else {
            outputRow.append(firstCharacter).append(secondCharacter);
        }

        // To replace subsequent ocurrance
        for (int i = 2; i < inputRow.length(); i++) {
            if (inputRow.charAt(i) != characterToEscape) {
                outputRow.append(inputRow.charAt(i));
            } else if ((inputRow.charAt(i - 1) == '\"' && inputRow.charAt(i - 2) == ',') || inputRow.charAt(i - 1) == ',') {
                outputRow.append(' ').append(inputRow.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return outputRow;
}
```

Comment: Use stringBuffer in `escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV` method and lastly return as outputString.toString();

Comment: @BhargavModi DO NOT use `StringBuffer` if thread-safety isn't required; `StringBuilder` is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @JacobG. questioner didn't gave any hint of using multi threading so thought to use string buffer.

Comment: That logic is backwards

Comment: I'd recommend to use a proper CSV library instead of dealing with these things yourself. See [here for a comparision of different libraries](https://github.com/robert-bor/CSVeed/wiki/Comparison-of-Java-CSV-libraries)

Comment: @Jacob already explored this in PoCs.
I believe StringBuilder are better for memory. Not sure about performance.
Plus StringBuilder does not have startsWith method.
Plus StringBuilder replace methods require you to provide start and end indexes. To get the index, adds more operations.
Overall it turns out be worse time-wise than the one written above.

Comment: @dpr As far as I know, libraries don't provide anything to verify if the data will trigger macro when opened in Microsoft Excel. Do let me know if there is anything for this.
As far as this post is concerned, we're trying to plug this in legacy code which has an existing way of writing the file. So just trying to put-in the best performing code

Comment: @Nikhil Seeing as that you don't wish to use a library, I'd love to know if my answer made it any more efficient!

Comment: *"To get the index, adds more operations."* - That's a wrong way of thinking. The problem with String is it's immutability. `String.substring(1)` creates a new String by copying all but the first character and that's expensive. That's why `StringBuilder` exists as the mutable buddy of `String`. The typical usage is iterating the original `String` and assembling the answer in the `StringBuilder` and it's very efficient. If you can do all your replacements it in a single pass, it'll be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

As dpr stated, it would be more beneficial to utilize a library dedicated to CSV parsing, as it would most likely be more efficient than my solution.  Nevertheless, if you would like to use pure Java, I believe the following should suffice:

```
public static String sanitizeInputForCSV(final String inputCSVRow) {
    StringBuilder outputCSVRow = new StringBuilder(inputCSVRow);

    escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(outputCSVRow, '=', '-', '+', '@');

    return outputCSVRow.toString();
}

public static void escapeMacroTriggersFromCSV(StringBuilder inputString, char... charactersToEscape) {
    for (char c : charactersToEscape) {
        // To replace the first ocurrance
        if (inputString.charAt(0) == '\"') {
            inputString.insert(inputString.charAt(1) == c ? 1 : 0, " ");
        }

        // To replace subsequent ocurrance
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            if (inputString.charAt(i) != c) {
                continue;
            }

            if (inputString.charAt(i - 2) != ',' && inputString.charAt(i - 1) != ',') {
                continue;
            }

            inputString.insert(i, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of creating numerous `String` objects, my solution utilizes a `StringBuilder` to save memory, and possibly perform more efficiently!

Comment: Thanks ! let me try it out and get some stats.

Comment: @Nikhil So how'd it go?

Comment: Your solution conserves memory, but you do expensive inserts which have to shift big parts if the string repeatedly. The key to efficiency here is to *avoid that by assembling the result in a different* `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Your code will throw exception as written above. After little change, it turned out to take half the time. It didn't click to use StringBuilder in this way and I was messing around with StringBuilder.replace.

Instead of passing the char array and looping over, calling the method 4 times with 1 character each time was faster.

And @maaartinus suggestion of not doing an insert but assembling the result in a different StringBuilder did magic to your method by further reducing time to half.

So what I finally have is one fourth time consuming of where we started with.

Comment: @Nikhil That's great!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to replace occurrences of any of `=-+@`, when they're at the string start, second just after a double quote, or after a comma or double quote.

This is the following pattern:

```
private static final Pattern TRIGGER_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("(^|^\"|,|,\")([-+=@])");
```

Now do just

```
String outputCSVRow = Pattern.matcher(inputCSVRow).replaceAll("$1 $2");
```

My understanding of your code might be wrong, but the principle stays the same. Note that the `Pattern` is simple and fast and `replaceAll` could process maybe a gigabyte in your 15 seconds.

You can also build a state machine yourself: Iterate through the input string and accumulate the result in a `StringBuilder`. You need a single pass, wo it will be really fast.

---

If you call your method just once, then this is equally good:

```
String outputCSVRow = inputCSVRow.replaceAll("(^|^\"|,|,\")([-+=@])", "$1 $2");
```

---

Regex has some overhead and you can usually do better with some hand-written code. Most of the time, it's not worth it, but you case may be an exception. Luckily, the equivalent code is very simple:

```
for (int i=0; i<in.length(); ++i) {
    char c = in.characterAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '=':
        case '@':
        if (i == 0 
            || in.characterAt(i-1) == ','
            || in.characterAt(i-1) == '"' 
                && (i == 1 || in.characterAt(i-2) == ',')
                ) {
            out.append(' ');
        }
    }
    out.append(c);
}
```

Some funny state machine could be even simpler and faster:

```
boolean hadComma1 = true; // was the last char a comma or are we at the start
boolean hadComma2 = true; // the char before
boolean hadQuote = false; // was the last char a double quote
for (int i=0; i<in.length(); ++i) {
    char c = in.characterAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '=':
        case '@':
            if (hadComma1 || hadComma2 && hadQuote) {
                out.append(' ');
            }
    }
    out.append(c);
    hadComma2 = hadComma1;
    hadComma1 = c == ',';
    hadQuote = c == '"';
}
```

Both snippets are fully untested.

Comment: thanks but this is slower than StringBuilder approach posted above by Jacob

Comment: @Nikhil Is it??? I know that predicting performance is hard, but I wouldn't expect it. Can you post you data somewhere, so I could give it a try myself? You could also try this regex instead `"((?:^|,)\"?)([-+=@])"` or `replaceAll("((?:^|,)\"?)(?=[-+=@]), "$1 ")`.

Comment: I chose to iterate through the `String` because I've always noticed regex to be slower, especially when attempting to replace characters.

Comment: I can't believe the current code from the other answer can be faster as it shifts the whole string. But I guess, you process the files line-wise which means that the string isn't that long.  `+++` Regex is slow when you do `s.replace(a, b)` as it has to be compiled every time its used. Using a `Pattern` is much faster, but yes, there's some overhead. Try my last snippet. You can also clear and reuse the `StringBuilder` for some more speed.